# It really should be ROY GBP?

Tags: meaning

I've read the [Color Survey Results](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/). There is a sentence:

Indigo was totally just added to the rainbow so it would have 7 colors and make that “ROY G. BIV” acronym work, just like you always suspected. It should really be ROY GBP, with maybe a C or T thrown in there between G and B depending on how the spectrum was converted to RGB.

What does it mean? I understood this acronym but why C or T? I translate this article into Russian, but do not understand the meaning letters C and T here. And why between G and B?

It really should be ROY GBP?

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with English. Marking as off-topic. That said, I expect C and T are two colours that fit in between Green (G) and Blue (B) that the writer expects could have been added instead of indigo.

Comment: C = cyan, probably.

Comment: C is Cyan and T is Teal. Both are a mixture of Green and Blue, so would appear between Green and Blue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where “[ROY G. BIV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_G._Biv)” stands for {Red    Orange    Yellow
    Green    Blue    Indigo    Violet}, the acronym “ROY GBP” would stand for {Red    Orange    Yellow
    Green    Blue    Purple}.  The phrase “C or T thrown in there between G and B” stands for “Cyan or Teal thrown in there between Green and Blue”, because (as seen in following diagram, taken from the [color survey results](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) link in the question) teal and cyan are the colors between green  and blue.  (Cyan is marked as the light bluish color in the top right corner of diagram.)

[image]

Comment: Pity you cannot represent spectral violet that way: it lies outside your RGB coordinates, and can only be shown as a red–blue metamere. Really, purple is only violet to people who don’t know color very much.

Comment: The split completely arbitrary and was only made into 7 to fit mystical/religous meanings of the number 7

Comment: @tchrist, yes, I thought about mentioning ROY GBP's purple anomaly.  Calling purple a metamere had not occurred to me – and perhaps still hasn't :)

Comment: Purple is non-spectral, but the idea of ROY G BIV is to create a spectral progression.  You have to use purple in an RGB system to mock up violet, because violet is below blue.